# Frontend part of component development question?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I written a module with a small form and this can submit every registred user, i insert this data in a extra table named: *#__trackitems*

I created a component with 1 view "tracks", the component is successfully added in navigation as menu item, i want now to get simple list with items from the table *#__trackitems*, view file is created and i see my static html, but what have i to do in model and controller? I tried more times to see how it is done in "com_content, com_k2 and com_weblinks" but i really not understand how to continue?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at the Joomla HelloWorld which is very basic: https://github.com/joomla/Joomla-3.2-Hello-World-Component/tree/step-10-adding-decorations-to-the-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:
Create model `Tracks` in `models` folder in your component containing a class `YOURCOMPONENTModelYOURVIEW` for example `TracksViewItems`. In this class add a public function called `getItems()`. Add all the code so this function will return array of items from your database table. Then in your `view.html.php` in `display()` function use this `$this->items = $this->get('Items')` to get a list of items from database. Now you can use `$this->items` property in your `default.php` of your view to get all the items.

#### Example:

If your component is called `com_tracks` and view is called `list` your model should be in: `/components/com_tracks/models/list.php`. Class name should be `TracksModelList`. Your view should be in `/components/com_tracks/views/list/view.html.php` and the view class name should be `TracksViewList`. In `/components/com_tracks/view/list/tmpl/default.php` you should insert all the code (html/php) for displaying your data from `$this->items` property.

#### Sample component tutorial:

[Developing a Basic Joomla! component](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Comment: Many thanks, sometimes are practical steps much more better :)

Comment: Link is now useless

Comment: The link is not useless but broken. Already fixed it.